# Failed to import bridging header facebook sdk

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, bridging-header

Hello guys I got this error when attempting to compile my file in swift:
[image]

I have added the frameworks: `FSBDKCoreKit`, `FBSDKLoginKit`, `FBSDKShareKit`, and `Bolt` to my root folder and not my `xcodeprojectworkspace`. But I'm receiving these errors. Please I need some assistance.

Also i added the frameworks in DealsApp-Bridging-Header:
[image]

Comment: did you set path of bridging header file in build settings -> Prefix header ?

Comment: @Jecky i deleted the sdks and reinstalled with cocoa pods and it works fine now.

Comment: Ok, then. When you want help contact me

Comment: @Jecky thanks and sure

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some days ago. Couldn't find why but when I tried to install the sdk with cocoa pods instead of just dragging the files it just worked.
Give this a try: https://edbinx.com/apple/ios/use-facebook-fbsdk-swift-cocoapods-ios-9-13369.html

Comment: yes i installed with cocoa pods as well and it works now

Answer (score 0):

From Errors, I think you need to add

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

in your file "DealsApp-Bridging-Header.h"

Comment: i added it in my DealsApp-Bridging-Header.h